# Row number with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to increase the row number of a partition based on a condition. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022412/incrementing-row-numbers-by-condition-in-postgres) refers to the same problem, but in my case, the column I want to condition on is another window function.

I want to identify the session number of each user (`id`) depending on how long ago was their last recorded action (`ts`).

My table looks as follows:

```sql
id  ts         
 1  2022-08-01 09:00:00 -- user 1, first session
 1  2022-08-01 09:10:00
 1  2022-08-01 09:12:00
 1  2022-08-03 12:00:00 -- user 1, second session
 1  2022-08-03 12:03:00
 2  2022-08-01 11:04:00 -- user 2, first session
 2  2022-08-01 11:07:00
 2  2022-08-25 10:30:00 -- user 2, second session
 2  2022-08-25 10:35:00
 2  2022-08-25 10:36:00
```

I want to assign each user a session identifier based on the following conditions:

- If the user's last action was 30 or more minutes ago (or doesn't exist), then increase (or initialize) the row number.
- If the user's last action was less than 30 minutes ago, don't increase the row number.

I want to get the following result:

```sql
id  ts                   session_id
 1  2022-08-01 09:00:00           1
 1  2022-08-01 09:10:00           1
 1  2022-08-01 09:12:00           1
 1  2022-08-03 12:00:00           2
 1  2022-08-03 12:03:00           2
 2  2022-08-01 11:04:00           1
 2  2022-08-01 11:07:00           1
 2  2022-08-25 10:30:00           2
 2  2022-08-25 10:35:00           2
 2  2022-08-25 10:36:00           2
```

If I had a separate column with the seconds since their last session, I could simply add 1 to each user's partitioned sum. However, this column is a window function itself. Hence, the following query doesn't work:

```sql
select
  id
  ,ts
  ,extract(
    epoch from (
      ts - lag(ts, 1) over(partition by id order by ts)
    )
  ) as seconds_since -- Number of seconds since last action (works well)
  ,sum(
    case
      when coalesce(
        extract(
          epoch from (
            ts - lag(ts, 1) over (partition by id order by ts)
          )
        ), 1800
      ) >= 1800 then 1
      else 0 end
  ) over (partition by id order by ts) as session_id -- Window inside window (crashes)
from
  t
order by
  id
  ,ts
```

> ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LAG()` window function to get the previous `ts` of each row and create flag column indicating if the difference between the 2 timestamps is greater than 30 minutes.
Then use `SUM()` window function over that flag:

```
SELECT
  id
  ,ts
  ,SUM(flag) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY ts
    rows unbounded preceding -- necessary in aws-redshift
  ) as session_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
    ,COALESCE((LAG(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) < ts - INTERVAL '30 minute')::int, 1) flag
  FROM
    tablename
) t
;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4afab7f986aca13072758623eeb4e295).

Comment: I think the error I was receiving is an AWS redshift bug. This solution was crashing because apparently you cannot `over (partition by id order by ts)` twice in a single query. I had to `order by` the subquery and omit the `order by` in `session_id`.

Comment: @ArturoSbr what you can't do is nest a window function inside another window function.

Comment: I really think this is a redshift issue. A copy-paste of your code still returns "com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause".

Comment: According to the documentation it is required to provide frame clause for aggregate af. Which is interesting https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_MAX.html

Comment: @ArturoSbr I thought you are using Postgresql. For redshift change to: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e19702ac205c1e17fb5ec4010b14247d

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick! I edited the question to add `rows unbounded preceding`, which apparently is necessary for running sums.

Comment: Only necessary if you use "order by".  SUM(A) OVER(partition by B) doesn't need an order by, it's meaningless (it doesn't matter in what order you sum values).  It only has meaning if you also have a frame clause.  So Redshift requires that you have both or neither - having 1 without the other implies that you are trying to do something but haven't fully specified it.  It's not a bug, it's a feature.